# TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=2846394]

Tags: graphics

My thesis contains appendices with a bunch of images listed side by side:

```
\begin{center}
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-01.35.23/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-01.48.37/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-02.01.51/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-02.16.52/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-02.29.57/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-02.43.04/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-02.56.16/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-03.09.29/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-03.22.44/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-03.36.04/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-03.49.00/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-04.15.37/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-04.28.57/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-04.42.23/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-04.55.52/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-05.09.06/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-05.22.31/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-05.35.56/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-05.49.30/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-06.15.55/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-06.29.29/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-06.42.40/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-06.56.04/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-07.09.21/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-07.22.56/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-07.36.19/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-07.49.47/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-08.03.21/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-08.16.46/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/MacroTopo_ctp=2_symtp=2_test_case=fixed-1_m=3_n=2_nmmcsx=4_nmmcsy=2_2022-03-13-08.43.38/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\hspace*{\fill}
\includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/best_compliance/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/median_compliance/Iter=1000} \hfill \includegraphics[width=3.5cm]{Periodic_EA-LSM_on_Graded_Structures/results/figures/graded-fixed-1/worst_compliance/Iter=1000}
\hspace*{\fill}\\[1cm]
\end{center}
```

The code block includes 30 images at the same time. Throughout the appendix, there are 300 images imported simultaneously by `\includegraphics` within this kind of code block. I got the following error message when I compile my document. The complier seems to complain the number of images is too large to process. How can I resolve this issue? (The path specified for the images is correct and images do exist.)

```
TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [pool size=2846394].
<argument> ...2_2022-03-13-03.09.29/Iter=1000.png
```

Comment: For a thesis, it is better to break 300 images into several figures - Separate 300 Figures with one image (& 2 Figures per one page) or Figures with subfigures consisting of 6 images at a time in a 3 X 2 matrix. Otherwise, it is hard to track all 300 images in the appendix of a Thesis as we need to refer to them with Figure Captions. (One figure with 300 subfigures constitutes a memory problem, I feel)..

Comment: @Dr.Sundar Doesn't a `\includegraphics` stand for a figure in my code example? So I use 300 `\includegraphics` to include 300 figures in my appendix.

Comment: Any ideas please?